# INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert group names into my database. Since they are usergroups I only want to insert them once, so if I accidentally insert them again it should refuse it because It already exists. I'm also using PDO statements.

```
// groups
$db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    name VARCHAR(200),
                    primary key (ID)
            )");        

// Fill tables

//Groups
$db = connectDatabase();    
$name = 'Administrator';
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO groups (name) SELECT :name WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name = :name)");
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();

$name = 'Moderator';
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO groups (name) SELECT :name WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name = :name)");
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();
```

For some reason its not adding anything to the table groups. Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks

Comment: You could try `REPLACE` which does INSERT if not exist and UPDATE if does (but name would have to be unique)

Comment: Can u use the same parameter twice in 1 query ?

Comment: if name should ne unique (are you sure you want this?) why not making it unique in db,and then mysql will complain if there already is one with same name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just make name **UNIQ**?

```
$db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    name VARCHAR(200),
                    primary key (ID),
                    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
            )");
```

And then make [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

```
$db = connectDatabase();    
$name = 'Administrator';
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO groups (name) VALUES (:name)");
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: The idea is right but you forgot to remove that useless `WHERE` part. it should be just simple conventional insert query

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `FROM` here

```
INSERT INTO groups (name) SELECT :name 
FROM groups WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name = :name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
If Not Exists(select * from groups where name=:name)
Begin
insert into groups(name) values (:name)
End
```